# How can I change the keybinding for repeating find character in vim?

Tags: vim

The default key to find the next character in vim is `;` but I have `;` mapped to `:`
So, I would like to repeat find character using `.`
How can I do this? Also, are there any disadvantages of doing this(Will it conflict with the behaviour of `.` )

Comment: Of course it will conflict with the original `.`. Why don't you just keep the default?

Comment: Don't do this. Keep ; as ; and never, ever touch .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you simply `:nnoremap ; .`, you'll lose the helpful original repeat functionality. You probably want to "overload" `.` to either repeat the last command, or the last `f` / `t` jump.

That's possible through [repeat.vim - Use the repeat command (.) with supported plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136), but it requires some effort. You need to overload the `f` / `t` commands to invoke `repeat#set("<Plug>OriginalSemicolon")`:

```
:nnoremap <Plug>OriginalSemicolon ;
:nnoremap <silent> f :<C-u>call repeat#set("\<lt>Plug>OriginalSemicolon")<CR>f
:nnoremap <silent> t :<C-u>call repeat#set("\<lt>Plug>OriginalSemicolon")<CR>t
```